# Successfully repeating a section of code using threading library in Python

Tags: python, pandas, timer, interactive

I'm working in Python3.5 and Interactive Brokers (IBPy2) and I want to execute a certain function every x minutes while incoming data are streaming.  I looked into various ways of doing it, but the one that seemed to be the most promising is using the threading.Timer() function.  When it executes, it DOES return what I want, but here are some of the errors that come out:

```
 Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1180, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Hobbies/Coding/connect-contract-order IB.py", line 76, in resample
    rs = ts.resample("1Min").mean()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3946, in resample
    base=base)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 760, in resample
    return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 861, in _get_resampler
    "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__)
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

I am essentially appending incoming values to a list, then every 60 seconds, I create a time-series from the list, and then resample that time-series.  I get multiple errors like the one above, except for different threads.  Any way to fix this?

Comment: There is problem `ts` has no `DatetimeIndex`. Maybe is necessary `ts.index = pd.to_datetime(ts.index)` but without data it is very hard find solution. What return `ts` ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought, but, it DID give me exactly what I wanted which was this:  2016-12-05 13:09:00    1.070556
2016-12-05 13:10:00    1.070526
Freq: T, dtype: float64

Comment: I have two input lists, one which is the data, the other, which is the DateTimeIndex.  I just am wondering why it is giving me the output but then constantly telling me that there isn't any.